# Is it possible to develop a clock and make it always displayed on screen in android device?

Tags: android, clock

I'm doing some tests and need a clock always displayed on screen even when playing a video in full screen mode.

Haven't done any android app, thus ask help here.
Is it possible to develop such a clock...?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

There is a component in android call SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW. Which is shown always on top.

For that you need to specify one permission in mainfest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>


WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
wm.addView(view, params);
```

Comment: BTW, I find a clock in google play, pretty close to what I want, just no millisecond: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=wan.util.showtime................Is this the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW?